# Composer update causing Laravel to not find class on server

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

This is a really strange thing I've found. I'm using Laravel's workbench on my Windows 7 system. Everything works perfectly, I have even pulled these packages onto other projects within my Windows environment and all is well.

The problem is when I have it installed on my CentOS server, it says can't find class ClassController@index. Now, here's the strange part, I can run composer dump-autoload -o and everything runs smooth until I update my package where I need to re-run composer dump-auoload -o.

Can anyone figure out what I need to change so it will always find my class? Or maybe this is a bug within Laravel?

I have my controllers listed in my autoload classmap within my composer.json.

I would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the Package Development workbench, you need to run the `composer install` in the root folder of your package as well.

Also:
The `-o` flag on dump-autoload command will convert all class loaders into class map. So if running that fixes your problem, I am guess the problem lies either with your PSR-0/4 autoloader or the class namespace.

Comment: Already done this and it's still happening. I just ran composer install in my main laravel directory and it fixed a part of it, but still get the same message on my other packages unless I run dump-autoload -o.

Comment: @CheckeredMichael I am not sure I understand what you meant. Adding some more information regarding your folder structure would be helpful.

Comment: Also, @CheckeredMichael the `-o` flag of dump autoload will convert all PSR-0/4 class loaders to class maps. So if running that fixes your problem, I would bet the problem lies with your `composer.json` class loader.

Comment: I'll take a look and add my file structure to this. This is one of those problems which works perfectly fine within my Windows environment, but not on Linux so just trying to pin point the exact problem.

Comment: Found out what it is, it was due to the fact I didn't have controllers in my autoload classmap. For some reason this didn't matter on my Windows machine and worked perfectly fine. I have however fixed the issue. :)